# SVG images dont appear after compiling PyQt4 python code with py2exe

Tags: python, svg, pyqt4, py2exe

I wrote python application using svg images as icons.

```
QtGui.QIcon(':icons/icon.svg')  <- just like this
```

it works on my comuter but after compiling it with py2exe and running on another computer, theres no icons.
if i try e.g. bmp format, all works fine. so i think it could be some library problem.
I don't know what PyQt4 uses for svg graphics.

in setup.py file i wrote

```
dllList = ('mfc90.dll','msvcp90.dll','qtnetwork.pyd','qtxmlpatterns4.dll', 'qsvg4.dll', 'qsvgd4.dll')
origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL
def isSystemDLL(pathname):
    if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in dllList:
        return 0
    return origIsSystemDLL(pathname)
py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL = isSystemDLL

setup(windows=[{"script" : "myApp.py"}], options={"py2exe" : {"includes" : ["sip", "PyQt4.QtNetwork", "PyQt4.QtWebKit", "PyQt4.QtSvg" ]}})
```

and also have imageformats folder (with qvg4.dll etc.)  included in myApp.exe directory

so how solve this problem?

thanks,
jarek

Answer (score 3):

The plugin used (Qt 4.6) is:

- plugins/

  - iconengines/

    - qsvgicon4.dll

You still need qt.conf as Ivo explained.

Comment: If you are willing to forgo the plugins folder (place iconengines in the toplevel application folder) then you do not need a qt.conf.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a `qt.conf` in your application's main installation directory (actually, the application's working directory), containing:

```
[Paths]
Plugins = <directory containing the image plugins directory>
```

So the directory layout is:

- app.exe
- qt.conf
- plugins/

  - imageformats/

    - qsvg4.dll

And then in this case, the directory in `qt.conf` is `plugins`.

Answer (score 0):

The `qsvg` plugin requires `QtXml`. Add `"PyQt4.QtXml"` to your includes.

Also see [library dependencies in Qt](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Qt_library_cross_dependencies).