# py2exe bundle_files=1 or 2 fails

Tags: python, pyqt4, py2exe

My application uses QGraphicsPixmapItem, and to make it able to load jpeg files I've placed qjpeg4.dll under 'imageformats' subdirectory in the 'dist' directory.
It works, but only as long as 'bundle_files' option is set to 3.
If I set it to 1 or 2, qt4 (pyqt4) is no longer able to find needed dlls, and so QGraphicsPixmapItems is not visible.

**setup.py:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    description = "",
    name = "name",
    windows = ["mainwindow.py"],
    zipfile=None,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to convince py2exe to include the dll by using:

```
setup(
      # other options,
      data_files=[('imageformats', 'qjpeg4.dll'),
      #other options
     )
```

For future reference, `data_files` should look like this (afaik):

`data_files = [ (dir1, [file1, file2, ...]), (dir2, [file3, file4, ...]), ...]`

**EDIT 1**: You could try using a directory structure like this ([source](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/plugins-howto.html)):

- yourapp.exe
- [qt.conf] (optional? see lower down)
- plugins/

  - imageformats/

    - qjpeg4.dll

And if **that** doesn't work, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434817/svg-images-dont-appear-after-compiling-pyqt4-python-code-with-py2exe) suggests using a `qt.conf` file that looks like this:

```
[Paths]
Plugins = <directory containing the imageformats directory>
```

Which apparently should work fine so long as the core dll `QtCore4.dll` has been included correctly (as it needs this .dll to interpret your qt.conf file).

Comment: I was able to convince py2exe to automatically add dll to the dist/imageformats directory, using data_files. Sadly, qt4 does not see it anyway.

Comment: No error message at all. Qt4 just silently fails to load jpeg file. QImageReader.supportedFormats() returns ('bmp', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'png', 'ppm', 'xbm', 'xpm'). If I change bundle_files to 3, the same function returns ('bmp', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'png', 'ppm', 'xbm', 'xpm').

Comment: Edited with more info. Hope that helps.

Comment: Nope. Sysinternals Process Monitor indicates that Qt4 is able to find and successfully load qjpeg4.dll in any case. But QImageReader does not reflect this in the case of bundle_files=[12]. I think I'll give up. I

Comment: ...I'm perfectly fine with bundle_files: 3 and InnoSetup.